# checkbox not returning current selection

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm running into a issue where the checkbox of input elements are not correctly returning checked or not checked status. 2 input checkbox elements are dynamically called via ajax with default checked and updated in div element using innerHTML, when I uncheck the same checkbox element on a form and submit, it is still showing me 2 checked input elements when there are none checked, it is not showing correctly the current selection of the checkbox after unchecked.

Here is my jquery code


`let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkboxele"]:checked');`

From my code values array should have nothing because I have unchecked 2 checkbox elements,
but when I print the values array I see there are 2 checkbox elements, probably from the default selection.

Comment: Can you show your html code too.

Comment: let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkboxele"]:checked');
                            let values = [];
                            checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => 
                            {
                                if (checkbox.checked === true)
                                {
                                     values.push(checkbox.value);
                                }
                            });